# I cant cd to my direction in Node.js command

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd

[There is the image, I cant enter the G folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2CJQ.jpg)

I have tried G:\
and G://
and the full name G:\AndroidProjects\ilk_flutter and with G:\AndroidProjects\ilk_flutter
and I tried all of them with the administrator please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cd` changes directory only. To change drive, just type drive name, along with colon `:`

First,

```
G:
```

and then

```
cd AndroidProjects\ilk_flutter
```

Comment: Whilst this two step procedure may work, the answer is incorrect. `CD` doesn't change directory only, you simply need to use the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Open a Command Prompt window, and type:

```
cd /?
```

Press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, and read the presented usage information.

The command is shown as:

```
CD [/D] [drive:][path]
```

And it specifically explains that you:

> Use the `/D` switch to change current drive in addition to changing current directory for a drive.

The solution is therefore to use that syntax:

```
CD /D "G:\AndroidProjects\ilk_flutter"
```

Answer (score 0):

Click in Address bar
https://kiranchauhan.tinytake.com/tt/NDYwNDg5N18xNDU5ODI2NQ

Then type 'cmd' only.

It will open the command prompt in that location directly.

Keyboard shortcut - ctrl+l, type 'cmd'